# MVC 5 with owin cookie middleware - owinContext.Authentication.sign in not issuing cookies

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, forms-authentication, owin

I am using MVC 5.2 and am trying to get the Owin cookie middleware working.

In my login controller i do the following:

```
public class LoginController
{

[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
    {

 //authenticate
     ....

        var claims = new List<Claim>
                         {
                             new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "abc"),
                             new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "abc@abc.com")
                         };
        var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();

        var authenticationManager = ctx.Authentication;

        //create the cookie - i thought

        authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties{IsPersistent = true}, id);


        //redirect to protected action
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "RoutingController");

  }


[Authorize]
public class RoutingController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return this.View();
    }
}
```

I have the following middleware wired up

```
   public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {           

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(
            new CookieAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                    LoginPath = new PathString("/Login/Login"),
                    CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always
                });
    }
```

Here is what happens

1. Get /Login/Login
2. Redirect to Routing/Index
3. Redirec to Login/Login

permanent 302 loop...

What am i missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost, AllowAnonymous, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }

    private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
    }
```

for the Antiforgery to work you shoudl also add this to your login page

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

Comment: thanks. the line that calls the user manager - my users will not be in a custom database and i may not use entity framework to read them. how does it work in that scenario?

Comment: @jonho

That would require a lot of work since they are supposed to be used together.

You would have to make your own implementation of the following.

IUserStore,
IUserPasswordStore,
IUserTwoFactorStore,
IUserClaimStore,
IRoleStore,
IUserSecurityStampStore,
IUserRoleStore,
UserManager

Comment: is there no other way to issue the cookie, without that line? thanks

Comment: I am currently using SessionAuthenticationModule to issue the cookie, but this ties me to IIS. Is there any other way to issue the Owin cookie. It seems weird that you have to have the EF dependency? thanks

Comment: `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(
                   new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = false }, ident);`